# How add current URL to the end of existing href link

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating some social share icons. For example the twitter share code is href="http://twitter.com/home?status="

The URL for the page you want to share goes after the = at the end of the link. Is there a way to add code that will add the current url of the page being viewed to the link address so that it doesnt have to manually be added on every page we want to put the button on?

Comment: The answer to your question is: Yes, there is a way.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this will work:

**HTML:**

Define an `id` so that the element can be uniquely identified.

```
<a id="tweeterUrl" href="http://twitter.com/home?status=">click here</a>
```

**JS:**

Change the `href` with js, after the page loads

```
window.onload = function () {
    var a = document.getElementById('tweeterUrl');
    a.href = a.href + document.URL;
}
```

Comment: Awesome, Thanks man I think that should work